# When getting the client's IP through a subdomain, it returns the server IP

Tags: php

I'm having an issue which is really testing me.
Let's say I have a PHP file on the main domain (www.domain.com) and a PHP file on the sub domain (www.sub.domain.com)

Each PHP file contains

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
```

I notice that the main directory returns my IP, yet the sub directory returns the server IP.

Why is this, and what can I do to stop this?
Thank you.

Comment: Is the request to the sub domain proxied at the server side? Sounds like your web server is running a reverse proxy configuration.

Comment: Something to note is that I set `allow_url_include` to 1 in php.ini on the subdomain root. Could this be the case? Also, @deceze how do I find out how it is proxied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include the subdomain php file into the main php file , by using it's url (like `include 'http://www.sub.domain.com/file.php';` , then PHP will get the parsed subdomain's file for you and put it inside the main file.

As php is getting that file, php's IP address is being used.

Rather than using `include 'http://www.sub.domain.com/file.php';` just use it's path ...

```
include '/path/to/subdomain/file.php';
```